# how to connect RSS feed with swift

Tags: ios, swift, rss

I want to make an application about news. I decided to use rss feed but somehow the rss feed doesn't come up.

Here are my code
This is how i declare variable

```
var parser = NSXMLParser()
var feeds = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var element = NSString()
var ftitle = NSMutableString()
var link = NSMutableString()
var fdescription = NSMutableString()
```

This is in my viewDidLoad function

```
    feeds = []
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string:"https://www.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss")!
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.shouldProcessNamespaces = false
    parser.shouldReportNamespacePrefixes = false
    parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = false
    parser.parse()
```

This is my didStartElement function.

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    element = elementName
    // instantiate feed properties
    if(element as NSString).isEqualToString("item"){
        elements = NSMutableDictionary.alloc()
        elements = [:]
        ftitle = NSMutableString.alloc()
        ftitle = ""
        link = NSMutableString.alloc()
        link = ""
        fdescription = NSMutableString.alloc()
        fdescription = ""
    }
```

This is my didEndElement

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {
    //process feed elements
    if(elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item")
    {
        if ftitle != ""
        {
            elements.setObject(ftitle, forKey: "title")
        }
        if link != ""{
         elements.setObject(link, forKey: "link")
        }
        if fdescription != ""
        {
            elements.setObject(fdescription, forKey: "decription")
        }
        feeds.addObject(elements)
    }

}
```

This is my foundCharacter function

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!) {
    if element.isEqualToString("title")
    {
        ftitle.appendString(string)
    }
    else if element.isEqualToString("link")
    {
        link.appendString(string)
    }
    else if element.isEqualToString("description")
    {
        fdescription.appendString(string)
    }

}
```

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath function

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        // Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel?.text = (feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("tittle") as String)
cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = (feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("description") as String)
return cell
```

Am i missing something? Any suggestion?